# Find pairwise intersection sum of L subsets of an Universal set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a universal set `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` and some L subsets as

```
L1 = {1,2,3,4}
L2 = {3,4}
L3 = {3,4,5,7} 
L4 = {5,6,7}
```

How would I to find all pairwise intersection value sums ?

For example, in the given example,

```
Pair 1 (L1,l2): intersection sum = 7 (3+4)
Pair 2 (L1,l3): intersection sum = 7 (3+4)
Pair 3 (L1,l4): intersection sum = 0 (no intersecting elements)
Pair 4 (L2,l3): intersection sum = 0
Pair 5 (L2,l4): intersection sum = 0
Pair 6 (L3,l4): intersection sum = 12 (5+7)
```

Currently, I am iterating through every possible pair and checking element by element. But this approach is not scalable. Complexity is $O(n^3)$. Is it possible to have an $O(n^2)$ approach or $O(n^3)$ is the least we could reach?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Find the intersections and add

Comment: Incidentally, it seems like $L_2 \cap L_3 = \{3,4\}$, summing $7$.